# Can we calculate entropy for nonstationary random variables?

Tags: entropy

Let's assume that $X$ is a discrete random variable, which can take any value from the set $\{x_0,\dots,x_n\}$ with the probability mass function $P(X)$. We can calculate the entropy of $X$ as follows,

$\text{Ent}(X) = -\sum\limits_{i=1}^n {P(x_i) \log P(x_i)}$

In above we assumed that the random variable $X$ has a stationary distribution. Can we define entropy for a non-stationary random variable?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13085/shannon-entropy-for-non-stationary-and-non-linear-signal

Comment: and http://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300/16/3/1493 :-)